# parallel programming for robot control

Tags: controls, parallel-processing, robotics

I need to write a program which does 2 tasks at the same time for better efficiency & high response. First task is, for example, get vision data from a camera & process it.

Second task is, receive processed data from first task & do sth else with this data (robot control strategy). However, while robot control task is being performed, the camera data receiving should still be working.

Is there a solution for such type of programming in C++/C#?? I'm learning TBB, is it the right choice? However, I'm reading things like "loop parallelization", am I going in the right direction??

This links to a very common style in control programming where the computer is used as a central unit to connect to electronic devices (sensors) & actuators and all these devices are processed concurrently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your example of loop paralleling is using parallel programming to speed up the result of a calculation for one set of data.

What you need is multitasking. You didn't mention any target architecture. Assuming this will be an embedded system, like a microprocessor, you have several options. There are embedded micro-OSes like VXworks and uC-OS that allow you to do just what you are asking. These allow you to set up multiple "tasks" that run virtually concurrently. Of course true concurrency is impossible with one CPU, but the scheduler in these OSes is designed to be very deterministic, for quasi-real-time systems like you describe.

Comment: yes, to be more specific. I'm using a core i7 desktop PC, win7. I'm trying to get feedback info from a camera and control the robot with this PC, VS2008 & OpenCV 2.1. How may I manage that? if it's multitasking, which tool to perform on my architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good to me!  TBB OK, C# has useful threadpool etc. classes.  Just one thing, if you haven't done anything like this before - it's all about the data, not the code.  If you design the data flow correctly, the code will write itself, (well OK, not really:).

Comment: yes. I've reviewed the TBB book. TBB is also used for game programming, dividing rendering, physics  task modules and parallelizing them. Then, I guess this applies for my problem, too. It's more about how to break up the big task to small parallel task units. Yet, this takes a long... time to learn. :|